# clean URL using php or .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

HOw to make this url:

```
http://localhost/TrustyWrenchVersionOOP/?page=home
```

to this url:

```
http://localhost/TrustyWrenchVersionOOP/home
```

Comment: By implementing rewrite rules in your http server. You will find many examples on google and here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your .htaccess rules like so. This is what I use and it works fine. There's different ways to achieve this, a quick google search probably would've yielded quicker results though

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: You could make the `/` optional with a `?`. That way only 1 rule is required.

Comment: Ah I see. Knew there was probably a way to make it `better` sadly my job doesn't involve much dev work, so I haven't really had to look into it D:

Comment: Thank you sou much it works fine